# Is there a way to read two paths from a directory?

Tags: c++, file

I want to read two paths on the computer and print them into a text file.

I'm using `filesystem` library, someone suggested me to add the paths to a `vector`, but I don't have any experiences with `vector`.

My problem is that I can't put two paths into a `for loop`, I put the code into a function and when I run the program I get a run time error in case that there is no memory on the computer.

How can I read two paths and put them in a text file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void fileslist()
{
    ofstream file;

    string pathdesktop = "C:\\Users\\roile\\Desktop\\";
    string pathdownloads = "C:\\Users\\roile\\Downloads\\";

    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(pathdownloads + pathdesktop)) {
        file.open(pathdesktop + "YourFiles.txt");
            file << entry.path();
    }

    file.close();
}

int main()
{
    fileslist();
}
```

My program is taking the files in the a specific directory, opening a text file and printing into the text file the files that in the directory.
I have opened and closed the file outside of the  `for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a directory iterator for the path given by the concatenation of your two paths, which does nox exist.

Use two nested for-loops

```cpp
for(const auto &p: {pathdownloads, pathdesktop})
{
    for(const auto &entry: fs::directory_iterator(p))
    {
     // do the work
    }
}
```

Also please don't use `using namespace std;`

Furthermore: Declare file in the outer for loop and initialize it directl from `p`.